# IllegalAccessError with spring boot application start up

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

Getting Below error after upgrading spring boot version from 1.2.6.RELEASE to 1.3.4.RELEASE

Earlier application was started fine with spring boot, but after upgrading the version application not starting up, any modification done to the latest version which I need to take care in my application to start.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addCollectionConverters(Lorg/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConverterRegistry;)V from class org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedConversionService
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedConversionService.<init>(RelaxedConversionService.java:52)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.modifyProperties(RelaxedDataBinder.java:148)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.doBind(RelaxedDataBinder.java:128)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.bind(DataBinder.java:631)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:269)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:241)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.bindToSpringApplication(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:230)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:181)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:152)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:126)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:55)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at com.gap.mosaic.trailerevent.ebo.integration.service.configuration.Application.main(Application.java:19)
```

Below are my gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core"
    compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jms"
    compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-xml"

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration:${springBootVersion}"

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:${springBootVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:${springBootVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:1.0.2.RELEASE"

    compile "org.springframework:spring-jms"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-oxm"
    compile ("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-mongodb"){
        exclude group: 'org.mongodb', module: 'mongo-java-driver'
    }

    compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.0.1"
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.4.1"
    compile "org.codehaus.castor:castor:${castor}"
    compile "xerces:xercesImpl:${xerces}"
    compile "xalan:xalan:${xalan}"
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1"
    compile "org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.2.3"
    compile 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.8'

    compile "com.ibm:mq-jmqi:7.0.1"
    compile "dhbcore:dhbcore:7.0.1.5"
    compile "com.ibm.mqjms:com.ibm.mqjms:com.ibm.mqjms"
    compile group: 'jms', name: 'jms', version: 'jms'
    compile group: 'com.ibm.mq', name: 'com.ibm.mq', version: 'com.ibm.mq'
    compile group: 'com.ibm.mq.headers', name: 'com.ibm.mq.headers', version: 'com.ibm.mq.headers'
    compile group: 'com.ibm.mq.pcf', name: 'com.ibm.mq.pcf', version: 'com.ibm.mq.pcf'
    compile group: 'com.ibm', name: 'mq-commonservices', version: '7.0.1'
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.2.0'

    testCompile("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-test") {
        exclude group: 'org.objenesis', module: 'objenesis'
    }
    testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5") {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    testCompile "com.github.fakemongo:fongo:2.0.4"
    testCompile ("com.mockrunner:mockrunner-jms:1.0.9") {
        exclude group: 'xerces', module: 'xerces'
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Information is not enough. And it seems like something cache, have you ever tried `clean` first when you try to package your application? Also probably related to your properties settings. Cause it's happened when binding some properties.

Comment: Yeah I clean my application and try to run still getting the same exception

Comment: Ok, then please recheck all your dependencies in `jar` or `war` which you've packaged and make sure all dependencies are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are overriding boot's Spring Framework version or you have an older spring version on the class path somehow.

`addCollectionConverters` was added to `DefaultConversionService` in Spring Framework 4.2.3.

Comment: Just want to say that I ran into this same issue, and it was because I had Spring 4.1.X on my project settings --> libraries path in IntelliJ.